# getting customers names

Tags: customer, model

I am trying to display all my users first and last names and email addresses to practice pulling values from the database and joining tables.

I have been trying to dig through the code in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model to see how to select specific values from two different tables. I can see the data I want is stored in customer_entity_varchar and customer_entity and is linked by the entity_id column but can't find an example of how I could achieve my desired result.

I have been working on the assumption that collections are the way to do it and so far have this

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

var_dump($model->getData());
```

but this shows all the columns and I just want email so I tried this

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

foreach($model as $cust){
    echo '<br/>' . $cust['email'] . '<br/>';
}
```

but I'm sure a collection would be a better way of doing it. Also I still need to join customer_entity_varchar but I can't find which model I need to use.

Firstly, how do I select customer email and full name? Secondly, Where should I have been looking in the code to get this answer?

===========

One last attempt I made was

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
    $model->getSelect()
          ->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix() . 'customer', 'main_table.entity_id = ' . Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix() . 'customer.entity_id', array('*'));

  var_dump($model->getData());
```

but got this `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magentostoretest.customer' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The customers collection is an EAV collection. This means you will have to add attributes to select when retrieving the collection. If it's not EAV you can replace `addAttributeToSelect` for `addFieldToSelect`.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('email');

foreach ($collection as $item)
{
   var_dump($item->getData());
   break; // just display one item
}
```

Comment: Thanks that has worked, but now my task is to understand why. On a very basic level does that mean, any EAV collections columns can be accessed by calling the column name? and how do I know its part of an EAV collection?

Comment: How EAV works and why it works that way is quite a large explanation. If you don't mind I'll refer you to http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-eav-system/ and http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-7-advanced-orm-entity-attribute-value

Answer (score 2):

**Get Customer collection :**

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname');


foreach ($collection as $collections)
{
   print_r($collections->getName());//Print full name of all customers

}
```

Comment: Works well. Also can use ->addAttributeToSelect('*') for access to all attributes assigned to customer(s)