# What performance gain will this code give?

Tags: database, performance

Code sample # 1

```
$customer_obj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
foreach(){
$customer_data = $customer_obj->load(customer_id);
$customer_data->getFirstname();
$customer_data->getEmail();
........
}
```

Code sample # 2

```
$customer_obj = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
foreach(){
$customer_obj->load(customer_id)->getFirstname();
$customer_obj->load(customer_id)->getEmail();
.........
}
```

The loop count will be something around 1800-2000 every day.It is one time cron job every day

I am assuming it in this way,
in sample # 1 `$customer_data` will have the entire customer details in memory and from there on wards it will fetch it from memory.but in sample # 2 it always hit db with every `load` call

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question:

code sample 1 is better, because it only does the load once for each customer.
code sample 2 does multiple loads per customer.

But as Patrick Steenks mentions, it is even much better to use a customer collection to do this, because then you only have ONE query for ALL customers :)

Comment: Thanks for that. But my customer base is almost 160,000. is it good to load that much of data in order to get the detail of <2000 customers?

Comment: @zamil You can Filter the collection to the IDs you want by using ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => array(1,2,3,4))) this Would get customers with IDs 1, 2, 3 and 4

Comment: Or you can filter with specific conditions. Do a google search on which attribute you want to filter and you will get enough results.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to use the collection method of magento, and then only load the attributes you need:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('firstname','email');
```

Then loop with a foreach through this collection.

Comment: This code will not work as needed. **[Edit: changed `addAttributeToSort()` to `addAttributeToSelect()`]** The argument to pass to `addAttributeToSelect()` is `addAttributeToSelect(array('firstname','email'))`.

Comment: I do not agree. You don't want to sort, but only select certain attributes. See also http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/getting-customers-names

Comment: Sorry typo. I meant that your code sample literally *will not work*. See [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract:: addAttributeToSelect()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.0.1/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php#L421).