# Display Customer Name in custom module grid column

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display customer name based on customer id in my custom module grid column.

Currently customer id only showing in the grid column. Please check attached image.
[image]

Comment: Just online from my mobile but I think this should help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11158/getting-customers-names

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding renderer in you column.
here is the example.

In your `_prepareColumns()` function of the Grid.php file add renderer in your Seller column

```
    protected function _prepareColumns() {
   //other columns data
  $this->addColumn('seller_id', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Seller Name),
    'align' => 'center',
    'index'     => 'seller_id',
    'type'  => 'text',
    'renderer' => 'Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Seller_Grid_Renderer_SellerName',     
 ));
 }
```

Create `SellerName.php` file in this location

```
app/code/{{your_code_pool}}/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Seller/Grid/Renderer/SellerName.php
```

and Add this code.

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Seller_Grid_Renderer_SellerName extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
    {
          public function render(Varien_Object $row)
          {
             return "your logic here to return seller name."
          }
    }
```

Replace Namespace_ModuleName with your Namespace and ModuleName.

Comment: But in this case search by name not working . Only search by id is working

Comment: For that you have to add 'filter_condition_callback' option in column in grid.php file.